# What is the simplest way to delete a child row when its parent is deleted, without knowing what its parent is?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, database-design

Given multiple entity types:

1. `Cluster`
2. `Hypervisor`
3. `VirtualMachine`

and given properties that could belong to any one of them (but *no more than one* per row):

- `CpuInfo`

  - `CpuSpeed`
  - `CpuTotal`
  - ...
- `DataStore`
- ...

What is the simplest way to delete a property with its parent?

## Attempted Solutions

### `ON DELETE CASCADE`

`ON DELETE CASCADE` seems to require a nullable foreign key for each possible parent, which strikes me as a poor design:

```
CREATE TABLE CpuInfo
(
    -- Properties
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CpuSpeed INT,
    AllocatedTotal INT,
    CpuTotal INT,
    AvailableTotal INT,

    -- Foreign keys for all possible parents
    ClusterId INT,
    HypervisorId INT,
    VirtualMachineId INT,

    FOREIGN KEY (ClusterId) REFERENCES Cluster(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (HypervisorId) REFERENCES Hypervisor(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (VirtualMachineId) REFERENCES VirtualMachine(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

### Junction Tables with Triggers

Parents are related to properties through junction tables. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE HypervisorCpuInfo
(
    HypervisorId INT NOT NULL,
    CpuInfoId INT NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (HypervisorId) REFERENCES Hypervisor(Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (CpuInfoId) REFERENCES CpuInfo(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

There is then a `DELETE` trigger for each entity type. The trigger selects the IDs of the entity's properties and deletes them. When the properties are deleted, the child junction rows are then deleted also, via `ON CASCADE DELETE`.

This doesn't model the business rules very well, though, since it allows the same `CpuInfo` to belong to multiple entities. It also adds a lot of tables to the design.

Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: If you seek for a solution which does not allow the same CpuInfo to belong to multiple entities, you can add a constraint to the three foreign keys. ALTER TABLE CpuInfo WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_keyIDs] CHECK  ((ClusterId IS NULL AND HypervisorId IS NULL AND VirtualMachineId IS NOT NULL) OR (ClusterId IS NULL AND HypervisorId IS NOT NULL AND VirtualMachineId IS NULL) OR (ClusterId IS NOT NULL AND HypervisorId IS NULL AND VirtualMachineId IS NULL))
GO

Comment: Hmm, I like that except that it isn't very DRY in that we have to add the same foreign keys to every property table. What if we add an `EntityProperty` junction table with the three nullable foreign keys with `ON DELETE CASCADE` for entities? The property tables could then have a single foreign key (also with `ON DELETE CASCADE`) for `EntityProperty`. Then deleting, e.g., a `Hypervisor` row would delete the `EntityProperty` row, which would delete the related property row. I wonder if that's too much overhead....Feel free to answer officially, by the way. Incorporate the preceding if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a "junction table" might be fitting for DRYness (it isn't a real junction because of the 1:n relation)

You could call your "junction table" a "super table" (something like "machine" [sorry I'm not native]):

In this table you put all the keys to your properties (make each foreign key column unique to ensure 1:1*). The very type of your "machine" (`Cluster`,`Hypervisor`,`VirtualMachine`) is in the "triple key" you already tried - also in the super-table.
To ensure "machine" is only of one entity add a constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE CpuInfo WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_keyIDs] CHECK (
(ClusterId IS NULL AND HypervisorId IS NULL AND VirtualMachineId IS NOT NULL)
OR (ClusterId IS NULL AND HypervisorId IS NOT NULL AND VirtualMachineId IS NULL)
OR (ClusterId IS NOT NULL AND HypervisorId IS NULL AND VirtualMachineId IS NULL)) GO
```

The good thing is you are quite free with your entities, you could allow a `PC` to be a `Cluster` at the same time.

*the key-column! the ID already has to be unique

Comment: Thank you, this works pretty well. One clarification re. the remark to "put all the keys to your properties" in the super table. I want to delete properties when entities are deleted, but *not* the other way around. So I ended up defining the relationship between properties and entities in the property tables themselves. The `machine` table, or `EntityProperty`, as I named it, has only the "triple key" with your constraint. Each property table then has a `FOREIGN KEY(EntityPropertyId)` to relate it to `EntityProperty`.

Comment: Come to think of it, `machine` *is* more appropriate than `EntityProperty`, since the latter implies junction, according to my naming convention. So thank you for that, too.